# SSIS not using correct dynamic DB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I've inherited a DB, and it gets errors because it's connecting to the wrong DB.

When I go to the connection in SSIS, and under expression, I see this formula:
@[$Project::myMDS_ConnectingString]

And in my environment variable, the seems to have not existed in the past so I created it. It now points to MDS007. However, the error is telling me that the SSIS is trying to connect to dev-MDS009.

I've tried rewriting the environment variables, and redeploying the package, neither have helped.

Any ideas as to what else I can do?

Comment: Does the package use a configuration file, maybe? You should be able to right-click in the Control Flow field and go to `Package Configurations...`. If it lists any config files, go check those to see if dev-MDS009 is specified as the server. If `@[$Project::myMDS_ConnectingString]` wasn't in the environment variables, it's probably in the package configuration.

Comment: Since you mentioned deploying it, perhaps the server has a stored config for it.